# Access the last line in console

Tags: c++, console, line

I want to access the last line of the console independent of the others. Only the possibility to write to/read from this last line is needed.

If there is a working way using the seekg and tellg function of cin/cout or any solution using the some cstdio function i wasn't able to find it.

Greets

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031462/how-do-i-write-over-the-last-line-in-the-console

Comment: @Seth: rewriting the line (or any random place in the terminal) is quite different than wanting read access to whatever was written there. That is not a candidate for being duplicate.

Comment: It is terminal case of amnesia if you can't remember the *last* line you wrote to the console.  Pun intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to do it with the standard library. You need an add-on package such as [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).